# Non-uniqueness of the Lagrangian

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

> The Hamiltonian for a simple harmonic oscillator is
>
> $$H(p,q)=\frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{k}{2}q^2$$
>
> Then a possible Lagrangian corresponding to $H$ can be
>
> 1. $L=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{q}^2-\frac{k}{2}q^2$
> 2. $L=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{q}^2-\frac{k}{2}(q^2+3q^2\dot{q})$
> 3. $L=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{q}^2+\frac{k}{2}q^2$
> 4. $L=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{q}^2+\frac{k}{2}(q^2+3q^2\dot{q})$

We know by Legendre transformation that

$$H = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\dot{q}-L=p\dot{q}-L$$

hence

$$L=p\dot{q}-H$$

Now since $H$ is given, by Hamilton movement equation we get

$$\dot{q}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}=\frac{p}{m}$$

Substituting $p = m\dot{q}$ in $L=p\dot{q}-H$ we get the expression as in $(1)$. But this only determines one Lagrangian uniquely whereas another possible Lagrangian is given to be $(2)$. How to prove $(2)$ is also another Lagrangian for the given $H$? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Adding a total derivative to a Lagrangian preserves the equations of motion (in this case there's just one, $m\ddot{q}=-kq$), but not the Hamiltonian, which instead undergoes a [canonical transformation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation).

Answer (score 1):

The second Lagrangian is not equivalent to the given Hamiltonian. Let
$$L=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{q}^2-\frac{k}{2}q^2-\frac{3}{2}kq^2\dot{q}$$
Then the momentum is
$$p=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}=m\dot{q}-\frac{3}{2}kq^2$$
Which means that the Hamiltonian is
\begin{align}
H
&=p \dot{q}-L\\
&=m\dot{q}^2-\frac{3}{2}kq^2\dot{q}-\frac{1}{2}m\dot{q}^2+\frac{1}{2}kq^2+\frac{3}{2}kq^2 \dot{q}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{q}^2+\frac{1}{2}kq^2
\end{align}
And clearly:
$$\frac{p^2}{2m}\neq  \frac{1}{2}m\dot{q}^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Considering

$$
L=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{q}^2-\frac{k}{2}(q^2+3q^2\dot{q})
$$

we have $H = p\dot q - L$ and here $p = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q} = m\dot q-\frac 32 k q^2$ so

$$
H(q,\dot q) = \frac 12(m \dot q^2+k q^2)
$$

now eliminating $\dot q$ into

$$
H = \frac 12(m \dot q^2+k q^2)\\
p = m\dot q-\frac 32 k q^2
$$

we get

$$
H(p,q) = \frac{1}{8m}\left(2p+3kq^2)\right)^2+\frac k2 q^2\ne \frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{k}{2}q^2
$$